# Popoup menu is clipped and not entirely visible

Tags: android, anchor, android-inflate, popupmenu

I want to show a popup menu anchored to the bottom of the screen but it always shows a popup anchored to the right-bottom of the screen.

This, sometimes, makes the popup menu being clipped when it is shown on the screen. [Here's an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPi0E.png)

Here is the anchor(item_menu) in layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/item_menu"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:visibility="visible">

   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:translationX="4dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my code to set the PopupMenu and display it:

```java
public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
   super(itemView);
   itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_menu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(final View view) {
         PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
         popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hot_item, popupMenu.getMenu());
         popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
               Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "menu clicked " + menuItem.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return true;
            }
         });
         popupMenu.show();
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: you need to change the code

Comment: Could you give me some more explanation? How can I change the code ?

Comment: thats aboiut as specific i can be without knowing the actual code